# Ruby: eliminate strings that are substrings of other strings in an array

Tags: ruby

I thought this would be an interesting question to post. I have a solution, I'm curious if there is a better way to do this. Say you have this array:

```
names = ["on", "question", "quest"]
```

I want to eliminate strings that are substrings of other members in the array. The cleanest code I could come up with is:

```
names.select do |name|
    names.all? { |other_name| other_name == name || other_name.match(name).nil? }
end
```

The result is

```
["question"]
```

I hate that code, just doesn't seem very ruby like. Any suggestions on a better / more efficient / more concise way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the `other_name == name ||` necessary?  Would be a bit cleaner without it.

Comment: Yes, otherwise everything would be excluded, including "question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a little addition to make. Use include? method of string

```
names.select do |name|
  names.one? {|other_name| other_name.include? name}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this easier

```
names.select do |name|
      names.one? {|other_name|  other_name.index(name)!=nil}
end
```

It checks if the item is a part of any one of the item in array.

Comment: Yep, that is better. Appreciate the help.

Comment: That can be shortened even more using `names.one? { |other_name| other_name[name] }`